# Unable to safely remove my harddrive since explorer.exe is holding on to it

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive

I am Unable to safely remove my harddrive since explorer.exe is holding on to it. I tested this with process explorer and it says there is a handle to F: being used by the explorer.exe.

I restarted explorer.exe and it still does not go away.

Then I see that in my explorer that there is an additional F: being shown. I am not able to explain hence please see the below image

[image]

I think its that additional F: apart from my drive name Sethu Entertainment that is causing the issue. I was not able to remove this, try as I might.

Comment: Are you able to safely remove the drive if you log off and then log back on?

Comment: Nope. Looks like the only way would be to shutdown the system. Is there any other way? Also this happens everytime I connect this drive. I remember adding this drive as a Video library to share it to my WLNA device. I think that's why that F: drive appeared. I am not able to remove it anymore.

Comment: In fact, the drive *do* have a sharing icon overlay. Do you see any sharing options enabled in the drive properties?

Comment: Yes it was..  Didn't see that earlier. I stopped sharing it and then tried safely removing. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the share icon gone now?

Comment: Yes it has gone

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12662/discussion-between-and31415-and-sethu)

Comment: try asking the same question in http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Right click on taskbar, start task manager, and kill process Explorer.exe

after that go to, File > run, write `explorer.exe` and hit enter

shell reloads.. retry removing the hard disk drive..

Hope it helps

Comment: It's better to let Explorer exit cleanly: right-click the taskbar while pressing Ctrl+Shift, and select `Exit Explorer` from the context menu.

Comment: I have tried that already. It still will not work.